# `cgpdftoraster` failure on Mac 10.11.6

Tags: macos, printing

I am trying to resolve a printing error for a relative's Mac.  The OS is 10.11.6, and I infer from her story that the printer (Epson Artisan 730) stopped working around the time of 10.11.6's release.

When I attempt to print, the print queue shows the job with a "Filter failed" message.  Frequently, cgpdftoraster will also crash, with an error report like below.  I have upgraded the printer firmware, installed all pending updates for the machine shown in the App Store, restarted, and removed/readded the relevant printer several times.  Searching with the `Symbol not found` string below, or with `cgpdftoraster`, has not turned up any promising leads.

Thoughts on reasonable next steps?  Should I upgrade to Sierra and hope?  Are there particular development packages I should install to satisfy cgpdftoraster?

```
Process:               cgpdftoraster [733]
Path:                  /usr/libexec/cups/filter/cgpdftoraster
Identifier:            cgpdftoraster
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        cupsd [693]
Responsible:           cgpdftoraster [733]
User ID:               26

Date/Time:             2016-11-22 14:26:18.368 -0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G1108)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        66E72A84-80D2-0E2C-FDD0-10A17CEB03C3


Time Awake Since Boot: 1200 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _getCurrentProfileID
  Referenced from: /usr/libexec/cups/filter/cgpdftoraster
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   dyld                            0x8fe2a085 dyld_fatal_error + 1
1   dyld                            0x8fe2ce72 dyld::bindLazySymbol(mach_header const*, unsigned long*) + 72
2   dyld                            0x8fe3dd9e stub_binding_helper_interface2 + 20
3   cgpdftoraster                   0x00007d9d 0x1000 + 28061
4   cgpdftoraster                   0x000026aa 0x1000 + 5802

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x96ca4d5e __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x914cc34b _pthread_wqthread + 1289
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x914c9f56 start_wqthread + 34

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x96ca57fa kevent_qos + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x99ea77ea _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 234
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x99ea73be _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x96ca4d5e __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x914cc34b _pthread_wqthread + 1289
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x914c9f56 start_wqthread + 34

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x8fe5f510  ebx: 0x00000001  ecx: 0x00000000  edx: 0x8fe8902c
  edi: 0x8fe8902c  esi: 0x8fe2cddc  ebp: 0xbfffb078  esp: 0xbfffb05c
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00000246  eip: 0x8fe2a085   cs: 0x0000001b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0x8fe57720

Logical CPU:     1
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     3


Binary Images:...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this problem on a recently buyed mac mini (end 2014 model) under El Capitan (10.11).

No good help from Apple assistance, nor by updates from Apple and Canon.

The problem was solved by passing to Sierra.

I've seen a lot of posts about the same problem under Sierra for Canon printers, dated of September and October 2016. It's seems to me that Canon or Apple ingeneers worked on the Sierra version of the problem, and solved it, letting aside the problem under El Capitan.

Hope it will help you.

Best regards

Benoit Lamberts

Comment: Note : The printer was a Canon Pixma MG5150 model

Comment: Upgrading to Sierra resolved my problem as well.  Thank you for the confirmation!